# Using list comprehension to calculate the sum of all list elements

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

Don't know if I'm just being stupid right now but I'm trying to convert a list of int to one int. The problem is that I am trying to do it with just a list comprehension but I'm failing every time

```
class MathStuff():
def add_stuff(self, *stuff):
    items = 0
    numbers = (i for i in stuff)
    items += [i for i in e]
#trying to do "for i in (i for i in stuff)" but assign it to a variable
```

I've tried multiple ways to do this without a "for loop" but I'm hitting a brick wall with my google searching.

Comment: Is `sum(stuff)` what you're looking for?

Comment: i think you should use`[]` brackets for list comprehension. Also, sum(stuff) would work just fine

Comment: I know about sum() but I'm trying to do it with a list comprehension if able to.

Comment: The whole purpose of a list comprehension is to *produce a new list*.  It is a completely inappropriate tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of numbers, `l`, and you don't want to use `sum`. I suppose you could do the usual:

```
l = range(1, 100)

s = 0
for i in l:
  s += i
```

Or a more functional approach.

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

l = range(1, 100)

reduce(add, l)
```

I don't see how comprehensions could help you solve this however.

Comment: You solved my issue, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept my answer in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use list comprehension, you can make a new list with an equal number of list entries as your input data. Then, flatten the list, and finally, use its length as the sum. You have to do this for positive and negative values separately, though:

```
long_pos = [[i for i in range(l)] for l in stuff if l > 0]
long_neg = [[i for i in range(abs(l))] for l in stuff if l < 0]
flat_pos = [i for sub in long_pos for i in sub]
flat_neg = [i for sub in long_neg for i in sub]
items = len(flat_pos) - len(flat_neg)
```